# Tableau Server (Linux) - tabadmincontroller crashing due to value 'warn'

Tags: java, tableau-api

Recently I was tasked to perform the following actions on our (single node) Tableau Server:

1. Harden the installation as per: https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/security_harden.htm
2. Increase the disk size of the attached volume (AWS EBS)
3. Change the instance type of the server.

Having no previous experience of Tableau, I:

1. Logged into the EC2 instance and ran:
   tsm configuration set -k ssl.protocols -v "all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1"
   tsm pending-changes apply

Waited for the changes to apply, and stopped the server

2. Increased the EBS volume size
3. Changed the EC2 instance type
4. Restarted the server.

Upon restart of the server, it took a while for everything to load. And everything appeared to be okay.... except for the admin panel and tsm command.

Running tsm status revealed:

`$ tsm status`

`Could not connect to server. Make sure that Tableau Server is running and try again.`

Okay. Checked the syslog (/var/log/syslog), which was pointed me towards tabadmincontroller as per:

```
systemd[1172]: Started Tableau Server Administration Controller.
tabadmincontroller_0[11354]: [11354] [INFO] 2021-11-24 13:13:47.106 +0000 : Loading configuration from /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/tabadmincontroller_0.20204.20.1116.1810/bin/tabadmincontroller.runjavaservice.json
tabadmincontroller_0[11354]: [11354] [INFO] 2021-11-24 13:13:47.107 +0000 : Loading configuration from /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/tabadmincontroller_0.20204.20.1116.1810/config/tabadmincontroller.runjavaservice.json
tabadmincontroller_0[11354]: [11354] [INFO] 2021-11-24 13:13:47.107 +0000 : Loading manifest from /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services

/tabadmincontroller_0.20204.20.1116.1810/bin/tabadmincontroller.jar
tabadmincontroller_0[11354]: [11354] [INFO] 2021-11-24 13:13:47.107 +0000 : Starting malloc_trim thread. Run every 60 sec. Heap pad MB: 1
tabadmincontroller_0[11354]: [11354] [INFO] 2021-11-24 13:13:47.109 +0000 : Loading JVM library /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/tabadmincontroller_0.20204.20.1116.1810/repository/jre/lib/server/libjvm.so
tabadmincontroller_0[11354]: [11354] [INFO] 2021-11-24 13:13:47.192 +0000 : Java class name: com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.TabadminController; Method name: main; Arguments: run
nlp_0[10759]: time="2021-11-24T13:13:54.323621681Z" level=info msg="[core] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = \"transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF\"" logger="pegasus/server:server" system=system
nlp_0[10759]: time="2021-11-24T13:14:05.775776702Z" level=info msg="get job counts" blockedJobCount=0 inProgressJobCount=0 logger="semanticmodel/metrics:Monitor" queuedJobCount=0 waitingJobCount=0
systemd[1172]: tabadmincontroller_0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1172]: tabadmincontroller_0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1172]: tabadmincontroller_0.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1172]: tabadmincontroller_0.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 7.
systemd[1172]: Stopped Tableau Server Administration Controller.
systemd[1172]: Started Tableau Server Administration Controller.
```

With an ongoing crash/restart loop going on forever.

Checking the logs at `/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/logs/tabadmincontroller`

shows the following:

```
2021-11-24 13:17:37.372 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=ip-172-33-30-206:8591 sessionTimeout=120000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@3657201c
2021-11-24 13:17:37.381 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util - Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation
2021-11-24 13:17:37.387 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket - jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2021-11-24 13:17:37.397 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2021-11-24 13:17:37.402 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Default schema
2021-11-24 13:17:37.408 +0000  main-SendThread(ip-172-33-30-206:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server ip-address-redacted. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
20redacted:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /ip-redacted:45082, server: ip/ip:8591
2021-11-24 13:17:37.423 +0000  main-SendThread(ip:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server, sessionid = 0x10000005ed60050, negotiated timeout = 120000
2021-11-24 13:17:37.432 +0000  main-EventThread : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
2021-11-24 13:17:37.780 +0000  main : ERROR com.tableausoftware.telemetry.helper.Environment - [xdev-edpa-007]  process_type is not present in the configuration
2021-11-24 13:17:38.298 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0 : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
2021-11-24 13:17:38.298 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0 : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=ip sessionTimeout=120000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@48dddf5a
2021-11-24 13:17:38.298 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0 : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket - jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2021-11-24 13:17:38.299 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0 : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2021-11-24 13:17:38.300 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0 : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Default schema
2021-11-24 13:17:38.300 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0-SendThread(ip:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server ip/ip:8591. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2021-11-24 13:17:38.301 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0-SendThread(ip:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: ip:45088, server: ip/ip:8591
2021-11-24 13:17:38.303 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0-SendThread(ip-172-33-30-206:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server ip-172-33-30-206/ip-address:8591, sessionid = 0x10000005ed60051, negotiated timeout = 120000
2021-11-24 13:17:38.303 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0-EventThread : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
2021-11-24 13:17:39.357 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-11-24 13:17:39.357 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-11-24 13:17:39.358 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2021-11-24 13:17:39.364 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@38e0ccf3{application,/,[file:///var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/temp/tabadmincontroller_0.20204.20.1116.1810/jetty-docbase.7353433006274726961.8850/],AVAILABLE}
2021-11-24 13:17:39.365 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @9503ms
2021-11-24 13:17:39.755 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
2021-11-24 13:17:39.756 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=ip-172-33-30-206:8591 sessionTimeout=120000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@6376534c
2021-11-24 13:17:39.756 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket - jute.maxbuffer value is 4194304 Bytes
2021-11-24 13:17:39.757 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=
2021-11-24 13:17:39.757 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Default schema
2021-11-24 13:17:39.758 +0000  main-SendThread(ip-172-33-30-206:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server ip-172-33-30-206/ip-address:8591. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2021-11-24 13:17:39.758 +0000  main-SendThread(ip-172-33-30-206:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /ip-address:45098, server: ip-172-33-30-206/ip-address:8591
2021-11-24 13:17:39.760 +0000  main-SendThread(ip-172-33-30-206:8591) : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server ip-172-33-30-206/ip-address:8591, sessionid = 0x10000005ed60052, negotiated timeout = 120000
2021-11-24 13:17:39.760 +0000  main-EventThread : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
2021-11-24 13:17:50.803 +0000  main : WARN  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20204.20.1116.1810/tabadmincontroller.jar!/com/tableausoftware/tabadmin/webapp/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cookieAuthenticationService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20204.20.1116.1810/tabadmincontroller.jar!/com/tableausoftware/tabadmin/webapp/auth/CookieAuthenticationService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.auth.CookieAuthenticationService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [int] for value 'warn'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "warn"
2021-11-24 13:17:50.806 +0000  Curator-Framework-0 : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2021-11-24 13:17:50.910 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x10000005ed60052 closed
2021-11-24 13:17:50.910 +0000  main-EventThread : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000005ed60052
2021-11-24 13:17:50.917 +0000  Curator-Framework-0 : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2021-11-24 13:17:50.930 +0000  Thread-15 : ERROR com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.EmbeddedLicenseActivator - Caught exception in EmbeddedLicenseActivator.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'nativeApiInitializer': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver$1.getTarget(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:90) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.hasEnoughRoleLicenses(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.impl.ProductKeyService.getLicensingState(ProductKeyService.java:373) ~[tab-tabadmin-controller-latest.jar:?]
    at com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.EmbeddedLicenseActivator$1.run(EmbeddedLicenseActivator.java:43) [tabadmincontroller.jar:?]
2021-11-24 13:17:50.935 +0000  Thread-15 : ERROR com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.EmbeddedLicenseActivator - Failed to activate the OEM embedded license.
2021-11-24 13:17:51.020 +0000  main-EventThread : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000005ed60050
2021-11-24 13:17:51.020 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x10000005ed60050 closed
2021-11-24 13:17:51.021 +0000  main : WARN  com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.agent.zookeeper.ConnectionHolder - Object ZooKeeperWorker@74b99b0e.  was not a consumer of this connection.
2021-11-24 13:17:51.022 +0000  Curator-Framework-0 : INFO  org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2021-11-24 13:17:51.124 +0000  ZKWorker-ScheduledTask-0-EventThread : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down for session: 0x10000005ed60051
2021-11-24 13:17:51.124 +0000  main : INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x10000005ed60051 closed
2021-11-24 13:17:51.142 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - node0 Stopped scavenging
2021-11-24 13:17:51.144 +0000  main : INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler - Stopped o.s.b.w.e.j.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext@38e0ccf3{application,/,[file:///var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/temp/tabadmincontroller_0.20204.20.1116.1810/jetty-docbase.7353433006274726961.8850/],UNAVAILABLE}
2021-11-24 13:17:51.154 +0000  main : INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-24 13:17:51.156 +0000  main : ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20204.20.1116.1810/tabadmincontroller.jar!/com/tableausoftware/tabadmin/webapp/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cookieAuthenticationService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/bin.20204.20.1116.1810/tabadmincontroller.jar!/com/tableausoftware/tabadmin/webapp/auth/CookieAuthenticationService.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.auth.CookieAuthenticationService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [int] for value 'warn'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "warn"
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction of the next steps here ?